# Socket error when installing eclipse using chef

Tags: eclipse, chef-infra

I am trying to install eclipse on ubuntu 12.04 using chef. Got the cookbook from the following site https://github.com/geocent-cookbooks/eclipse

I have also downloaded all the dependencies that eclipse cookbook showed like chef_handler, windows and ark. I have downloaded these using the "knife cookbook download site" command.

When i run the eclipse cookbook i get the following socket error. I am working from behind a proxy. And have set the proxy correctly. All other cookbooks are working fine except eclipse.

Please find the error log below.

````
[2014-06-17T05:38:15+05:30] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
[2014-06-17T05:38:15+05:30] WARN: Chef client 306 is running, will wait for it to finish and then run.
[2014-06-17T05:38:43+05:30] WARN:
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
SSL validation of HTTPS requests is disabled. HTTPS connections are still
encrypted, but chef is not able to detect forged replies or man in the middle
attacks.

To fix this issue add an entry like this to your configuration file:

```
  # Verify all HTTPS connections (recommended)
  ssl_verify_mode :verify_peer

  # OR, Verify only connections to chef-server
  verify_api_cert true
```

To check your SSL configuration, or troubleshoot errors, you can use the
`knife ssl check` command like so:

```
  knife ssl check -c solo.rb
```

* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *

[2014-06-17T05:38:43+05:30] INFO: *** Chef 11.12.8 ***
[2014-06-17T05:38:43+05:30] INFO: Chef-client pid: 422
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] INFO: Setting the run_list to ["recipe[eclipse-master]"] from CLI options
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] INFO: Run List is [recipe[eclipse-master]]
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] INFO: Run List expands to [eclipse-master]
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] INFO: Starting Chef Run for ubuntu
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] INFO: Running start handlers
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] INFO: Start handlers complete.
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] INFO: WindowsPackage light-weight resource already initialized -- overriding!
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for execute[eclipse plugin install] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] WARN: Previous execute[eclipse plugin install]: /home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/eclipse-master/recipes/default.rb:44:in `block in from_file'
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] WARN: Current execute[eclipse plugin install]: /home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/eclipse-master/recipes/default.rb:44:in `block in from_file'
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] WARN: Cloning resource attributes for execute[eclipse plugin install] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] WARN: Previous execute[eclipse plugin install]: /home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/eclipse-master/recipes/default.rb:44:in `block in from_file'
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] WARN: Current execute[eclipse plugin install]: /home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/eclipse-master/recipes/default.rb:44:in `block in from_file'
[2014-06-17T05:38:57+05:30] INFO: Processing package[openjdk-6-jdk] action install (java::openjdk line 46)
[2014-06-17T05:38:58+05:30] INFO: Processing package[openjdk-6-jre-headless] action install (java::openjdk line 46)
[2014-06-17T05:38:58+05:30] INFO: Processing java_alternatives[set-java-alternatives] action set (java::openjdk line 50)
[2014-06-17T05:39:15+05:30] INFO: Processing link[/usr/lib/jvm/default-java] action create (java::default_java_symlink line 16)
[2014-06-17T05:39:15+05:30] INFO: Processing ruby_block[set-env-java-home] action run (java::set_java_home line 19)
[2014-06-17T05:39:15+05:30] INFO: ruby_block[set-env-java-home] called
[2014-06-17T05:39:15+05:30] INFO: Processing directory[/etc/profile.d] action create (java::set_java_home line 26)
[2014-06-17T05:39:15+05:30] INFO: Processing file[/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh] action create (java::set_java_home line 30)
[2014-06-17T05:39:15+05:30] INFO: Processing package[libtool] action install (ark::default line 22)
[2014-06-17T05:39:15+05:30] INFO: Processing package[autoconf] action install (ark::default line 22)
[2014-06-17T05:39:16+05:30] INFO: Processing package[unzip] action install (ark::default line 22)
[2014-06-17T05:39:16+05:30] INFO: Processing package[rsync] action install (ark::default line 22)
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] INFO: Processing package[make] action install (ark::default line 22)
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] INFO: Processing package[gcc] action install (ark::default line 22)
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] INFO: Processing package[autogen] action install (ark::default line 22)
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] INFO: Processing ark[eclipse] action install (eclipse-master::default line 31)
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] INFO: Processing directory[/usr/local/eclipse-kepler] action create (/home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/ark/providers/default.rb line 39)
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] INFO: Processing remote_file[/home/test/chef-solo/eclipse-kepler.tar.gz] action create (/home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/ark/providers/default.rb line 45)
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] WARN: remote_file[/home/test/chef-solo/eclipse-kepler.tar.gz] cannot be downloaded from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-jee-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz&r=1: Error connecting to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-jee-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz&r=1 - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
[0m
================================================================================[0m
[31mError executing action `create` on resource 'remote_file[/home/test/chef-solo/eclipse-kepler.tar.gz]'[0m
================================================================================[0m

[0m
SocketError[0m
-----------[0m
Error connecting to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-jee-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz&r=1 - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known[0m

[0m
Resource Declaration:[0m
---------------------[0m
# In /home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/ark/providers/default.rb

 45: remote_file new_resource.release_file do
 46: Chef::Log.debug('DEBUG: new_resource.release_file')
 47: source new_resource.url
 48: checksum new_resource.checksum if new_resource.checksum
 49: action :create
 50: notifies :run, "execute[unpack #{new_resource.release_file}]"
 51: end
 52:
[0m

[0m
Compiled Resource:[0m
------------------[0m
# Declared in /home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/ark/providers/default.rb:45:in `block in class_from_file'

remote_file("/home/test/chef-solo/eclipse-kepler.tar.gz") do
  provider Chef::Provider::RemoteFile
  action [:create]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  path "/home/test/chef-solo/eclipse-kepler.tar.gz"
  backup 5
  atomic_update true
  source ["http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-jee-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz&r=1"]
  use_etag true
  use_last_modified true
  cookbook_name :"eclipse-master"
end
[0m

[0m
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[0m
================================================================================[0m
[31mError executing action `install` on resource 'ark[eclipse]'[0m
================================================================================[0m

[0m
SocketError[0m
-----------[0m
remote_file[/home/test/chef-solo/eclipse-kepler.tar.gz] (/home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/ark/providers/default.rb line 45) had an error: SocketError: Error connecting to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-jee-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz&r=1 - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known[0m

[0m
Resource Declaration:[0m
---------------------[0m
# In /home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/eclipse-master/recipes/default.rb

 31: ark "eclipse" do
 32: url eclipse_url
 33: version node['eclipse']['version']
 34: extension "tar.gz"
 35: has_binaries ['eclipse']
 36: append_env_path true
 37: action :install
 38: end
 39:
[0m

[0m
Compiled Resource:[0m
------------------[0m
# Declared in /home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/eclipse-master/recipes/default.rb:31:in `from_file'

ark("eclipse") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Ark
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  guard_interpreter :default
  cookbook_name :"eclipse-master"
  recipe_name "default"
  url "http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-jee-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz&r=1"
  version "kepler"
  extension "tar.gz"
  has_binaries ["eclipse"]
  append_env_path true
  prefix_bin "/usr/local/bin"
  home_dir "/usr/local/eclipse"
  path "/usr/local/eclipse-kepler"
  release_file "/home/test/chef-solo/eclipse-kepler.tar.gz"
  strip_components 1
  owner "root"
  group 0
end
[0m

[0m
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /home/test/chef-solo/chef-stacktrace.out
[2014-06-17T05:39:17+05:30] ERROR: ark[eclipse] (eclipse-master::default line 31) had an error: SocketError: remote_file[/home/test/chef-solo/eclipse-kepler.tar.gz] (/home/test/chef-repo2/cookbooks/ark/providers/default.rb line 45) had an error: SocketError: Error connecting to http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-jee-kepler-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz&r=1 - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
[2014-06-17T05:39:18+05:30] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
````

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you got configured proxy in knife.rb

```
http_proxy 'http://PROXY_IP:3128'
https_proxy 'http://PROXY_IP:3128'
no_proxy 'localhost, 192.168. *'


knife [: bootstrap_proxy] = 'http://PROXY_IP:3128'
knife [: bootstrap_no_proxy] = 'localhost, 192.168 *.'
knife [: publisher] = "vim"
```

the bootsraping node has to be done with this knife in the client configuration.

On the node in / etc / chef / client.rb should be this:

```
log_level: auto
log_location STDOUT
chef_server_url "https://CHEFSERVER.domain.com:443"
validation_client_name "chef-validator"
# Using default node name (fqdn)
http_proxy "http://PROXY_IP:3128"
https_proxy "http://PROXY_IP:3128"
no_proxy "localhost, 192.168. *"
```

sorry for my english

best regards.